# How do I initialize this specific variable?

Tags: java, variables, methods, initialization, boolean

So I have this method:

```
public MazeLocationList solve(){
    boolean solved = true;
    int startrow = x[0][0];
    int startcol = x[0][0];
    MazeLocationList path;
    boolean S = findPath(startrow, startcol, 15, 20);
    if (S == false){
        solved = false;
        return null;
    } else {
        return path;
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is I'm trying to check if the method findPath returns true or false and then returns different things depending on if it's true or false. The problem is the variable path hasn't been initialized and I'm not quite sure how to initialize it because I want to return path if it's the method findPath is true.

Comment: MazeLocationList path; is this has any default value? or you need to calculate somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

There is a major flaw in your code.

`path` is a method local variable. So, it cannot be accessed in other methods unless it is passed as an argument.

Since in your `findPath` method, you don't get / pass `path`, returning path actually makes little sense.

You could initialize `path` to either `null` or `new MazeLocationList()` but it won't do any good since `path` is not being changed.

Answer (score 1):

Your variable path doesnt get any value at all, so it doesnt matter if it is initialized or not.

What is the idea of returning path if the value is never changed?

EDIT:

If you only want to return an instance of `MazeLocationList`, just do

```
MazeLocationList path = new MazeLocationList();
```

or instead of returning path, return an instance:

```
return new MazeLocationList();
```

Like that:

```
public MazeLocationList solve(){
    boolean solved = true;
    int startrow = x[0][0];
    int startcol = x[0][0];

    boolean foundPath = findPath(startrow, startcol, 15, 20);

    if (!foundPath){
        solved = false;
        return null;
    }

    return new MazeLocationList();
}
```

Comment: What I'm attempting to do is return an instance of MazeLocationList however I'm not quite sure how to do that.

Comment: See my edit above. If you just wanna return an instance, initialize it with a new instance of MazeLocationList or just return it in the if statement.

Comment: Now I get a compiler error that says MazeLocationList is abstract and cannot be instantiated. What the program is supposed to do is return an instance of MazeLocationList and if there's no path for the findpath method then it just returns null. I'm just confused over what it means to return and instance of MazeLocationList.

Comment: Well I cant see the implementation of the class MazeLocationList, but if its abstract means that its a class which cannot be instantiated. I dont know the idea of your whole code, but an abstract class is used by creating an inheriting subclass that can be instantiated.